# Sequence contains more than one matching element with guid as ID

Tags: c#, entity-framework, guid

I'am trying to use GUID as id and get the error message

> "Sequence contains more than one matching element"

Model

```
public class HeatImage
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ImageId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Insert in db with GUID

```
foreach (var file in files)
{
    var myGuid = Guid.NewGuid();

    var heatImage = new HeatImage {ImageId = myGuid, name = file.ToString()};
    db.HeatImages.Add(heatImage);
}
```

Comment: I think you have submit the changes after adding when you are submit or savechanges ?

Comment: Could you post the stack trace?

Comment: It works fine if I use int id auto increment

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public Guid ImageId { get; set; }
```

I think the reason is your GUID always null while you inserting.

Comment: How GUID is NULL he assigned a GUID before insert a record

Comment: Dhaval may be u r right. But in my memory I have same problem before.
the reason is null.